# Why can I call instance functions statically?

Tags: c++, oop, static, instance

I was looking around the Notepad++ source code on GitHub recently, and [came across](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/blob/master/PowerEditor/src/Notepad_plus_Window.cpp#L42) a method call like this:

```
Window::init(hInst, parent);
```

I searched for the function it was referencing to, and came across a [`Window`](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/blob/master/PowerEditor/src/WinControls/Window.h#L40-L44) class- but the `init` function was marked `virtual`, so clearly it was non-static. Thinking I made a mistake, I checked the entire header to make sure there was no static overload of `init`, and I made sure there was no `Window.cpp` file. There isn't.

After poking around the source for 15 more minutes, I gave in and `git cloned` the repo locally so I could open it in Visual Studio. The first thing I did was to build just to make sure this wasn't an accidental merge on behalf of the project developers- the build succeeded.

The next steps I took:

- I opened the the file calling `Window::init` and clicked `Go To Declaration` on `Window`. It takes me to the `Window` class.
- I clicked `Go To Declaration` on the `init` function. It points me to the signature of the virtual method.
- I copy and paste the `Window.h` file into an entirely new header and replace all references of `Window` with `Foo`. When I type in `Foo::init`, the compiler complains that 'a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object'.

**TL;DR:** Somehow, the Notepad++ source code calls a non-static method statically, and this builds. Doesn't work with any other class. Proof [here](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/blob/master/PowerEditor/src/Notepad_plus_Window.cpp#L42) and [here](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/blob/master/PowerEditor/src/WinControls/Window.h#L40-L44).

I have spent 2 hours staring at this, but I still don't see how it's possible. Am I missing something?

Comment: That's how you call the base function in an overriding virtual function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not calling a static function. It's just calling the base class's version of `init()`. Basically, in `tClassName::f`, you are asking "I want to call that specific version of the virtual function `f()` in class `tClassName`".

Generally, it's pretty common to call the base class's counterpart of a virtual function in the derived class. E.g., the factory method pattern:

```
#include "tObject.h"
#include "tObject1.h" // public inheritance from tObject
#include "tObject2.h" // public inheritance from tObject
#include "tObject3.h" // public inheritance from tObject

class BaseFactory
{
public:
   // factory method
   virtual tNode *createObject(int id)
   {
      if (id == 1) return new tObject1;
      else return new tObject2;
   }
};

class DerivedFactory: public BaseFactory
{
public:
   virtual tNode *createObject(int id)
   {
      // Overrides the default behavior only for one type
      if (id == 1) return new tObject3;
      // Call the default factory method for all other types
      else return BaseFactory::createObject(id);
   }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

> Am I missing something?

Yes - context.  `Notepad_plus_Window` derives from `Window`, and the call to  `Window::init()` is inside of the `Notepad_plus_Window::init()` method:

```
class Notepad_plus_Window : public Window { 
public: 
    ...
    void init(HINSTANCE, HWND, const TCHAR *cmdLine, CmdLineParams *cmdLineParams); 
    ...
};
```

```
void Notepad_plus_Window::init(HINSTANCE hInst, HWND parent, const TCHAR *cmdLine, CmdLineParams *cmdLineParams) 
{ 
    ...
    Window::init(hInst, parent); 
    ...
}
```

In this context, `Notepad_plus_Window` is calling the base class `Window` version of `init()`.

Comment: Ah, can't believe I missed that, especially given that the name of the class was `Notepad_plus_Window`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will confuse you less. You're missing context, at no real fault of your own.

You're not seeing the implicit `this` in the call.

Take the following example:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
public:
  virtual void bar() {
    std::cout << "Foo" << std::endl;
  }
};

class Bar : public Foo {
public:
  virtual void bar() {
    std::cout << "Bar" << std::endl;
  }
};

int main() {
  Bar bar;
  bar.bar();        //-> bar
  bar.Foo::bar();   //-> foo

  Bar *barp = &bar;
  barp->bar();      //-> bar
  barp->Foo::bar(); //-> foo

  return 0;
}
```

In the above, we can specify the object on which to call a specific method in the class' hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a static function. It's calling a function with a specified (class) scope.

By default, init() will match functions within current class scope, if they do exist. that is an implicit this call, equals this->init(),

But with a specified class/namespace prefix, you can explicit call any particular function without dynamic binding. i.e. ::init() will call the init() function within global scope.

the following code may give you a better understanding

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
  virtual void  test()
  {
      std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
  }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    virtual void test()
    {
        std::cout << "B" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A* a = new B();
    a->A::test();
    return 0;
}
```